# CGImage Masking with UIImage pngData()

Tags: ios, swift, image, mask, masking

I'm trying to mask an image in swift. Here's my code:
(Normally, `originalImg` is an image that is loaded from `UIImagePickerController` and then cropped by `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`, and
`makedImage` is an image that is drawn by the user, created by `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`)

```
func imageMasking(_ originalImg: UIImage, maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let cgMaskImage = maskImage.cgImage!
    let mask = CGImage(maskWidth: cgMaskImage.width, height: cgMaskImage.height, bitsPerComponent: cgMaskImage.bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel: cgMaskImage.bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow: cgMaskImage.bytesPerRow, provider: cgMaskImage.dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true)!
    return UIImage(cgImage: originalImg.cgImage!.masking(mask)!)
}
```

When I display the resulted `UIImage` to `UIImageView`, it works well. However, when I try to get the `pngData()` of the resulted `UIImage`, the image data is identical to `originalImg`.

I also tried to export the `pngData()` of the resulted image from Xcode, but it is still the same as `originalImg`.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK8fK.jpg (then click the 'Export...' button and save as png image)

How can I *really* mask an image?

Comment: I think you can render the result of imageMasking into bitmap context and get result image from the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just draw a masked image into [image context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1623922-uigraphicsbeginimagecontext?language=objc):

```
func drawImage(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage?
    {
        guard let coreImage = image.cgImage else {
            return nil;
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: coreImage.width, height: coreImage.height))
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: coreImage.width, height: coreImage.height))
        let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resultImage;
    }
```

Also you can draw image into [bitmap context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/1455939-init) or [image renderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/drawing?language=objc) and get result image.

Comment: It works! Can you explain why you need to draw it to image context before calling `pngData()`? Also, why `UIImage` can show the masked image before drawing to image context? Thx!

Comment: iPhone is a small device with small size of memory, but with strong GPU. Many components and methods of the SDK is lazy, for example if you create UIImage you will not load binary data into memory, data will be loaded late. Methods of CGImage, that can produce other images work in lazy way. You do not copy data when create CGImage via other CGImage. (In same way work CIImage, UIImage, CGImage, CGBitmapContextCreateImage, and many other components of the SDK)